# Yii ajaxLink pass parameters from dropdown and submit using POST method

Tags: jquery, yii

I would like to retrieve selected value from dropdown and pass it using Yii's ajaxLink function via POST method.

I can retrieve the values in the `beforeSend` part, for example,

```
array( // ajaxOptions
    'type' => 'POST',
    'beforeSend' => "function() {                                  
         start_time = jQuery('#start_time').find(':selected').val();
         end_time = jQuery('#end_time').find(':selected').val();

         this.data += '&start_time='+start_time;
         this.data += '&end_time='+end_time;
    }",
    .......
```

I can format the string, pass it and parse it in the controller but I'm using protection from CSRF and if I pass parameters as a single string I get "CSRF token could not be verified" error.

Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in a form and submit it (via an AJAX request) - then the form will POST it as usual, and you don't have to munge any values.  Alternatively, you could attach AJAX directly to the dropdown via htmlOptions, e.g.:

```
<form>
<?php
    echo CHtml::listBox('field', '', $fieldData,
        array('ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'url' => Controller :: createUrl($controllerAction),
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>'function(data) { console.log(data) }'
            ),
        )
    );  
?>
```

This way, the detail will get submitted via the form POST; you can do any munging you need in PHP after you've got the value submitted.

If you need a submit type item, I'd use an ajaxSubmitButton() instead of an ajaxLink(), and then you're getting all the form data.